# Getting back old DS-160 form data

Tags: visas, usa

I applied for a USA student visa back in 2012 but unfortunately I could not remember some of the information I gave back then and I still cant find the previous print out.

I don't know if it can be retrieved back because I'm intending to apply for a visa and I don't want to mix up in my information, I don't know if there could be another way to get back my data.

Comment: Rule #1 of visa applications - Don't Lie!  You never know when it'll come back to haunt you...

Answer (score 3):

You may be able to [make a request to the US Department of State for your records](https://foia.state.gov/Request/Visa.aspx). I'd make it clear in your request that you're requesting your DS-160 specifically.

It's a fairly convoluted process: you'll have to draft your own request letter that complies with their requirements, and the website seems to be indicating that the only way to get it to them is to send it in by postal mail or fax. The wait for a response, especially given the pandemic, could potentially be extremely lengthy.